# Dynamicically adding divs not making an equal grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to dynamically add a bunch of divs to create a grid of a certain size. My code is is follows:

```
function genGrid(v) {
    var e = document.getElementById('container'); //This is what we want to append the rows to
    for (var i = 0; i < v; i++) {
        var row = document.createElement("div"); // This creates each row.
        row.className="row"; // This declares the class name for the created div.
        for(var j = 0; j < v; j++) {
            var cell = document.createElement("div");
            cell.className="cell";
            $('.cell').css("width", (960/v));
            $('.cell').css("height", (960/v));
            row.appendChild(cell);
        }
        e.appendChild(row);
    }
}
```

However for some reason whenever I call the genDivs function with a parameter of 4, the code creates a 3x4 grid, instead of a 4x4 grid. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly why your code is not working but I've corrected your code, change these lines -

```
$('.cell').css("width", (960/v));
$('.cell').css("height", (960/v));
```

to these -

```
$(cell).css("width", (960/v));
$(cell).css("height", (960/v));
```

here is the working fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/55v2skmb/